# What is the easiest method to get name of folder (a version number) in which batch file is running?

Tags: batch-file

I have this folder structure:

C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder\**Version**\**Version**_IMS

I have a batch script in C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder\**Version** that needs to enter the directory **Version**_IMS
The **version** can be for example **5.3.12.0** and is not constant as it changes. So I cannot know it.

I need in the script to extract the last directory it is in for example **5.3.12.0** and then I can enter to **5.3.12.0**_IMS.

What is the easiest way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0.") do cd /d "%%~fa\%%~nxa_IMS"
```

Where

`%~dp0` is the drive and path of the current batch file

`%%~fa` is the full path to the element being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`

`%%~nxa` is the name and extension of the element being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`.

So, we retrieve a reference to the folder that contains the batch file, get the name of that folder and use it to enter (i have used `cd`) into the child folder

Comment: for some reason this is not working I replace the "cd" with echo and get: /d "Folder\SubFolder\5.2.15.37\\_IMS" The 5.2.15.37\\_IMS is real and the other part I replaced... looks like something with the %%~nxa not working...

Comment: @ilayzeidman, sorry, a typo error. I missed to include a dot. Answer updated.